# Java ArrayList IndexOutOfBoundsException despite giving an initial capacity

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

When I do

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
arr.set(0, 1);
```

Java gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(Unknown Source)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:13)
```

Is there an easy way I can pre-reserve the size of ArrayList and then use the indices immediately, just like arrays?

Comment: If you want an array, use an array. The point of `ArrayList` is to enable you to use the higher-level operations such as `add`.

Comment: I think it might be giving you an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because `set` does the following: `Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element`.  Since there is no element at index 0 to replace, an exception is thrown.  Try using `add` and seeing if the size is modified past your indicated capacity.  If this is not what you are looking for, I suggest the answer given by @jh314

Comment: What would be a rationale behind such use case? I think you're trying to find out how to misuse the pattern rather than try to understand it.

Comment: @AlexBrooks, see my answer, you're correct, but not because there's no element.

Comment: @SteveP. Makes perfect sense.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This is a common design(it's the same in python too): `set` methods do *not* increase the size of a sequence/collection. If you want to increase the size then you want to `add` something.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's the source from `ArrayList`:

The constructor:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) 
{
     super();

     if (initialCapacity < 0)
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+ initialCapacity);
     this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
}
```

You called `set(int, E)`:

```
public E set(int index, E element) 
{
     rangeCheck(index);  
     E oldValue = elementData(index);
     elementData[index] = element;
     return oldValue;
}
```

`Set` calls `rangeCheck(int)`:

```
private void rangeCheck(int index) 
{
    if (index >= size) {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
    }
}
```

It may be subtle, but when you called the constructor, despite initializing an `Object[]`, you did not initialize `size`.  Hence, from `rangeCheck`, you get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, since `size` is 0.  Instead of using `set(int, E)`, you can use `add(E e)` (adds `e` of type `E` to the end of the list, in your case: `add(1)`) and this won't occur.  Or, if it suits you, you could initialize all elements to 0 as suggested in another answer.

Comment: While now I finally understand how it works, I still think this designer's choice is stupid and counter-intuitive.

Comment: @CodeNoob No problem.  I agree that the term *capacity* is misleading, but I think that it actually makes sense for it to be this way.  `size` keeps track of how many elements are actually in the array, so it makes sense for `size` to be 0 right after initialization, and with regards to `set/add`, as Bakuriu said: *"This is a common design (it's the same in python too): set methods do not increase the size of a sequence/collection. If you want to increase the size then you want to add something."*

Comment: It makes more sense if you consider that ArrayList implements the List interface. A List has no concept similar to "Initial Capacity". A list grows by adding values to it.

Answer (score 25):

How about this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(10, 0));
```

This will initialize arr with 10 zero's.  Then you can feel free to use the indexes immediately.

Comment: This worked. nCopies expects objects (not null)? if so then use NullObject pattern.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue here is that although you have suggested the allocated space of entries in the Array, you have not actually created entries.

What does `arr.size()` return?

I think you need to use the add(T) method instead.

Comment: It's not that he hasn't created entries, see my answer.  The `add(T)` is a good suggestion, though.

Answer (score 2):

Programming aside, what you are trying to do here is illogical.

Imagine an empty egg carton with space for ten eggs. That is more or less what you have created. Then you tell a super-precise-and-annoying-which-does-exactly-what-you-tell-him robot to replace the 0th egg with another egg. The robot reports an error. Why? He can't replace the 0th egg, because there is no egg there! There is a space reserved for 10 eggs, but there are really no eggs inside!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `arr.add(1)`, which will add `1` in the first empty cell, i.e. the 0-indexed one.

Or you could create your own list:

```java
public static class PresetArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PresetArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
        super(initialCapacity);
        addAll(Collections.nCopies(initialCapacity, (E) null));
    }

}
```

Then:

```java
List<Integer> list = new PresetArrayList<Integer>(5);
list.set(3, 1);
System.out.println(list);
```

Prints:

```
[null, null, null, 1, null]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an Java-specific answer but an data structure answer.

You are confusing the `Capacity` concept with the `Count` (or `Size`) one.

Capacity is when you tell the list to reserve/preallocate a number of slots in advance (in this ArrayList case, you are saying to it create an array of **10** positions) in its' ***internal storage***. When this happens, the list still does not have any items.

Size (or Count) is the quantity of items the list really have. In your code, you really doesn't added any item - so the IndexOutOfBoundException is deserved.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't do what you want with arraylist, there is another option: Arrays.asList()

Answer (score 0):

Capacity is used to prepare `ArrayList`s for expansion.  Take the loop

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(final int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
    list.add(i);
}
```

`list` [starts off](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28%29) with a capacity of `10`.  Therefore it holds a new `Integer[10]` inside. As the loop adds to the list, the integers are added to that array.  When the array is filled and another number is added, a new array is allocated twice the size of the old one, and the old values are copied to the new ones.  Adding an item is O(1) at best, and O(N) at worst.  But adding N items will take about `2*1024` individual assignments: amortized linear time.

Capacity isn't size.  If you haven't added to the array list yet, the size will be zero, and attempting to write into the 3rd element will fail.